# Having issue publishing Node.js project to azure web service

Tags: node.js, azure

I got this error when I publish to Azure web service.
I installed and see that package mentioned in the error ipaddr.js in the node_modules folder though

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error TS6053  File
> 'C:/CodingProjects/OrderPickUp_App/OrderPickUp_App/node_modules/ipaddr.js'
> not found.   The file is in the program because:
> Root file specified for compilation   OrderPickUp_App JavaScript Content Files        1   Active

Answer (score 0):

Few of the workarounds to solve the `Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error TS6053 File .js' not found.`

- Restarting the Visual Studio / Visual Studio Code / IDE
- Remove `%temp%` data
- If Restarting the IDE appears the same error, try Opening the IDE > `file - Folder` Close and re-open `File - Open Folder`

Please check the workarounds which is a kind of similar error from [Ref1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35893723/typescript-ts6053-file-ts-not-found), [Ref2](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/ts6053-node-modulessource-mapsource-map-not-found/1412153) which resolves this kind of errors.